# How do I cat a deleted file which is still open by its inode?

Tags: macos, terminal, hfs+

I have deleted a file I still have open. I want to save that file. I know its inode number.

I think that sleuthtools `icat` would work for me except for the following.

`$ sudo icat -f hfs /dev/disk0s2 3720257 > /path/to/some_new_filename`

```
Error opening image file (raw_open: file "/dev/disk0s2" - Resource busy)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the block disk `/dev/disk0s2` is in use by the Kernel, use the raw disk:

/dev/rdisk0s2