# Error Opening Image File in Terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line

Much like: [How do I cat a deleted file which is still open by its inode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98774/how-do-i-cat-a-deleted-file-which-is-still-open-by-its-inode).

I am using 'Sleuth Kit' command line tool, to gather relevant data from the disk. But I keep on getting:

`Error opening image file (raw_open: file "/dev/rdisk1s2" - Permission denied)`

This is so, whether or not I included `r`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you running this via sudo or as your own user?

Comment: own user. must I use sudo?

Comment: Yes as the data is not necessarily yours. My general comment is if you don't know if to use sudo you need to learn more about what you are doing as using sudo can delete all your data or install a virus

Answer (score 1):

In order to access a raw disk device **/dev/rdisk1s2**, it should not be mounted. Open `Disk Utility` and unmount it first. Otherwise you would get a **Permission denied** error when you try to access it as a raw device.

If you wish to (or need to) have it mounted and use the block device, remove the "r" from the disk name, making it **/dev/disk1s2** (notice the missing "r" before "disk1s2").

Comment: even with r or w/o r, mounted or not, I still get "Permission denied". what else can be the problem?

Comment: Are you using `sudo`?